# Need to use COUNT inside WHERE/HAVING to return opened and closed

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, count, where-clause

[NumberWrittenByOperator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWAPW.png) 
[NumberRemovedByOperator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StHEm.png)

I am using the following SQL in MsAccess:

```
SELECT [TagRegister Query - All].ReportedBy AS WrittenBy,
       Count([TagRegister Query - All].ReportedBy) AS Written,
       Count([TagRegister Query - All].RemovedBy) AS Removed
FROM [TagRegister Query - All]
GROUP BY [TagRegister Query - All].ReportedBy, [TagRegister Query - All].RemovedBy;
```

I created a query off of a table, and this is looking up data from the query. I am trying to count the number of Anomalies Reported (ReportedBy/Written) and the number of Anomalies Removed (RemovedBy/Removed).

Suppose the operator reported 5 Anomalies - but he only removed 1, a mechanic removed 2, and the remaining 2 are still 'open'. but with this I am getting

```
WrittenBy   Written  Removed 
Operator      1        1 
Operator      2        2 
Operator      2        0
```

I would like it to return something more like this:

```
WrittenBy   Written  Removed  Ratio
Operator      5        1       20%
```

I want to see how many he has written, how many he has removed, and how he is performing - removing anomalies he reports

I can make a query to return the number Anomalies Reported, as well as a separate query to return the Anomalies Removed.  I am struggling to build a query to return both within the same query.

Can you guys help me out?

I'm happy to provide as much as I can, still new to Stack Overflow, so bear with me.

The pictures show the number written by each operator, and the number that operator removed.  So one can write anomaly, and have someone else close it. If it is possible I would like to show the number they have written, and the number they have removed.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I dont' understand how you get 5 written and 1 removed from your sample data.  Surely it'd be 3 removed?

Comment: I want to see the number written by the operator, and the number the operator removed.  For this report, I only need to see what the operator written and removed, and do not need to included ones removed by the mechanic.

Comment: Based on the data shown, it's impossible to tell that two of the units removed should be ignored. Your source query is insufficient for the task at hand.

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: The operator name would be in the ReportedBy column as well as the in the RemovedBy column. Is there a way to count where the operator name from RemovedBy matches ReportedBy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add to the returned columns of your query the column `[TagRegister Query - All].RemovedBy`:

```
SELECT [TagRegister Query - All].ReportedBy AS WrittenBy,
       [TagRegister Query - All].RemovedBy,
       Count([TagRegister Query - All].ReportedBy) AS Written,
       Count([TagRegister Query - All].RemovedBy) AS Removed
FROM [TagRegister Query - All]
GROUP BY [TagRegister Query - All].ReportedBy, [TagRegister Query - All].RemovedBy;
```

Then use conditional aggregation on that query like this:

```
SELECT t.WrittenBy,
  SUM(t.Written) AS Written,
  SUM(IIF(t.RemovedBy = t.WrittenBy, t.Written, 0)) AS Removed,
  ROUND(100.0 * Removed / Written, 2) & "%" AS Ratio
FROM (
    SELECT q.ReportedBy AS WrittenBy,
           q.RemovedBy,
           Count(q.ReportedBy) AS Written,
           Count(q.RemovedBy) AS Removed
    FROM [TagRegister Query - All] AS q
    GROUP BY q.ReportedBy, q.RemovedBy 
) AS t
GROUP BY t.WrittenBy
```

I used aliases to make the code shorter and more readable.

Comment: Let me try this out real quick!

Comment: That was it! Perfect.  Thanks, so much!

Comment: Last question. I need to put in a 'Round' clause in there to not have 25.92384877520938475%  Where does that go in all of this?

Comment: If you mean the Ratio then see my edited answer. Change 2 to the number of decimal digits that you need.